# Python Unittest mock issue

Tags: python, unit-testing

Under project/scripts directory,
main.py

```
Class BaseClass:
  fun1(self):
    print(“fun1”)
  fun2(self):
    print(“fun2”)

def run():
  try:
    v=BaseClass()
    v.fun1()
    v.fun2()
  except:
    log.exception(“Failed”)
```

Under project/tests directory
test_main.py

```
from main import BaseClass, run
from unittest import mock, TestCase

Class TestRun(TestCase):
  def test_run(self):
    with mock.patch(‘scripts.main.BaseClass’) as mock_base:
      mock_base.return_value = mock.Mock( **{ 
             ‘fun1.return_value’ : True, ‘fun2.return_value’: True })
      run()
      mock_base.assert_called()
      mock_base.assert_called_once(fun1)
      self.assertTrue(mock_base.called)
```

Issue is run() is not picking up the mocked BaseClass, hence assertions failing.
Please can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is that you must patch an object at the place where it is used. Here you call the `run` function that you find in a `main` module (`from main import BaseClass, run`). So you should patch `BaseClass` directly in the `main` module:

```
from main import BaseClass, run
from unittest import mock, TestCase

class TestRun(TestCase):
  def test_run(self):
    with mock.patch('main.BaseClass') as mock_base:
      mock_base.return_value = mock.Mock( **{ 
             'fun1.return_value' : True, 'fun2.return_value': True })
      run()
      mock_base.assert_called()
      mock_base.assert_called_once()
      self.assertTrue(mock_base.called)
```